# how to go to next line in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a relative layout that contains two `LinearLayout`. So when I `setText`(id is `companyText`) and its longer text it goes to above in another `TextView` (id is `companyDistance`)

When `companyName` has longer text I want it go to next line and not go avobe to second layout
for more clear see attached pics

[image]

But I want it will be like in this pics

[image]

Here is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/secret_logo_small"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyImageView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Secret"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="154"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/companyPercentImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyDistance"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_indicator_dagavit"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/small_green_button_add_icon"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use RelativeLayout use LinearLayout.

Here is complete answer for your question. Good luck.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/secret_logo_small"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyImageView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Secret"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="154"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/companyPercentImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyDistance"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_indicator_dagavit"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/small_green_button_add_icon"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it might work, but it more efficient to use relative layout instead of linear layout

Comment: @pmb if it helped you, please accept this answer. This will help other users with the same/similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your textview:

```
android:maxLines="10"
```

Then use `\n` in the text of your TextView.

maxLines makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. You may choose another number :)

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not a good solution for me this time.

Comment: Add '\t' for tab and '\n' for new line

Answer (score 0):

First, add an ID to your first LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
```

And in your second LinearLayout you need to add the attribute

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_linear
```

so your xml will look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_linear">
```